# NSArray count and adding 1 in if statement

Tags: nsarray

I am trying to get the count of an array and add it by 1 in an if statement and it does not seem to work. It causes a crash. Is this the right way to do it or am I doing something wrong?

```
if (currentPicture == [pictureArray count] +1) {
    currentPicture = 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you doing with `currentPicture`?

Comment: Every time a button is clicked, in my case the next picture, it will add one to currentPicture. If it is the previous picture, it will subtract one from currentPicture. currentPicture is a NSUInteger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSArray`'s range is from `0` to `count - 1`. If you want to "wrap around" by setting the index to 0 once you reach the end, then you have to do:

```
if (currentPicture == [pictureArray count]) {
    currentPicture = 0;
}
```

`count + 1` is one too far.

Comment: You sir just saved the day! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

== is a comparison operator, so you are saying that if the value of currentPicture is the same as the count of pictureArray plus one, then set currentPicture to zero.

Are you sure you can just set currentPicture to zero?

Comment: Yes because the array is always going to be 1 or more so its not like the if is going to run forever. Would there be any other reasons why I can't set currentPicture to zero?

Comment: It seems as if the if is not getting called... Here is whats from the console...  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSArray objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'